# nasm enter two real numbers into 2 different arrays

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to enter real numbers into 2 different arrays

currently I have this code, but it seg faults right after i'm done entering the last float value into array2,

any ideas?

```
segment .bss
;
segment .data
prompt1     db  "Do you have data to enter? (-1 = yes,0 = no)?: ", 0
prompt2     db  "Enter your Float Value: ", 0   
prompt3     db  "Almost done ",0
segment .text
    extern readdouble,print_string, read_int
    global readarray
readarray:
    pusha
    mov ebx, [esp+36]   ;move starting position into ebx
    mov esi, [esp+40]   ;move max values into edx
    mov edi, 0      ;initialize counter to zero
read_loop:      
    mov     eax, prompt1
    call    print_string
    call    read_int    ;read in decision for prompt
    inc     edi;        increment counter
    cmp eax, 0  
    jz  Done_reading_array1
    jmp continue_loop
continue_loop:
    mov eax, prompt2
    call    print_string
    call    readdouble
    mov     [ebx], ecx  ;move value into memory slot ebx
    mov [ebx+4], edx

    add ebx, 8      ;move to next location for db word
    jmp read_loop
Done_reading_array1:
    sub edi, 1
    mov [esp+40], edi   ;moves counter back to stack
    jmp read_array2
read_array2:
    mov ebx, [esp+68]   ;move starting location of array1 into ebx
    ;mov    esi,[esp+80]    ;move number of items into esi  
    mov ebp, 0
continue_readarray2:
    mov eax, prompt2
    call    print_string

    call    readdouble
    mov     [ebx], ecx  ;move value into memory slot ebx
    mov [ebx+4], edx

    inc ebp
    add ebx, 8      ;move to next location for db word

    cmp ebp, edi
    jz  done_reading_array2
    jmp continue_readarray2

done_reading_array2:
    ;mov    [esp+72],edi
    mov eax, prompt3
    call    print_string
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: Why on earth are you writing this in assembly language?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using EBP like that in the second loop as you're screwing up the stack frame - why not use ESI for the counter instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you doing any bounds-checking on the length of the allocated array in `readarray`.  For instance (and maybe it's because your labeling is messed up here), but you seem to set `EBX` to the starting value of the array, and set `ESI` to the length of that array.  But nowhere inside of `read_loop` and `continue_loop` can I detect you're actually checking the value of `ESI` to see if you can keep incrementing the value of `EBX` by 8-bytes for the quad-words being returned from `readdouble`.  Somewhere in that loop before you increment `EBX` you're going to have to check against the available remaining length of the allocated memory array being pointed to by `EBX`, which is a value I'm assuming you can construct from the information passed into `ESI` (and hopefully none of the functions you're calling destroy `ESI`, otherwise you're going to have to save that value to the stack or into another callee-save register).

Hope this helps,

Jason